# Using api or ordinary route in Laravel for search suggestions?

Tags: laravel

I just started learning Laravel and now I'm building an application where I need a textfield that fetches results from a model based on what the user types in the textfield. I'm using ajax to query the database, but should the endpoint be implemented as an api, or can I use an ordinary route in web.php for this? Any cons not using api?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to perform the search.
If you want a dropdown list that change typing you need to send the text written whit js via api, get the resoults.

But when you click in the lense icon you can perform the search with the controller.

To avoid different resuolts you can create a trait that perform the query for you in each cases.